# Multiple form classes in django generic (class) views

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'd like to use the class based generic views of django 1.3 for forms, but sometimes have to manage multiple form classes in one form. However, it looks like the existing views based on FormMixin assume a single form class.

Is this possible with generic views and how would I do it?

EDIT: to clarify, I have one form but more than one (ModelForm based) class. For example in the inline_formset example in the django docs, I would want to present a page where an author *and* his books can be edited at once, in a single form:

```
author_form = AuthorForm(request.POST, instance = author)
books_formset = BookInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author)
```

Comment: There's not really any way Django could merge model forms without resolving field name collisions in some way which might not be obvious. Additionally, the recipient of the form would then need to split the form amongst several models. `ForeignKey` relationships further complicate things, as in your example, because then some means of adding and removing things (books in your example) is needed. (Actually, it's even worse, because a robust model would realize that the relationship from book to author is actually `ManyToManyField`, since books can have multiple authors.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Facing similar problem, I've come to conclusion that it's not possible.

Though having multiple forms per page itself turned out to be a design mistake, presenting all sorts of troubles. E.g., user fills two forms, clicks submit on one of them and loses data from the other. Workaround requires complicated controller that needs to be aware of the state of all forms on the page. (See also [here](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?design.4.363620.12) for some discussion on related problem.)

If having multiple forms per page isn't your exact requirement, I'd suggest to look at alternative solutions.

For example, it's usually possible to show user only one **editable** form at a time.

In my case, I switched to `django-formwizard` (<s>not a django.contrib one, which is a bit old and seems to be currently under a redesign, but [this one](http://github.com/stephrdev/django-formwizard)</s> *Update:* Beginning with release 1.4 of Django, `django-formwizard` app will be available in `django.contrib`, replacing old formwizard. It's already in trunk, [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)). For the user I made it to look like there are actually multiple forms on the page, but only one is editable. And user had to fill forms in predetermined order. This made dealing with multiple forms much easier.

Otherwise, if forms *really* need to be presented all at once, it may make sense to combine them into one.

---

UPDATE (after your clarification):

No, you can't deal with formsets using generic `FormView` either. Though your example appears to be quite simple to implement: I think it's very similar to [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) in Django docs on formsets. It deals with two formsets, and you just need to replace one with the form (I think you still need to specify prefix to avoid possible clashes of elements' `id` attributes).

In short, in your case I'd subclass `django.views.generic.base.View` and override `get()` and `post()` methods to deal with form and formset similar to above example from Django docs.

In this case, I think it's fine to present both form and formset editable—with a single button to submit them both.

ANOTHER UPDATE:

There's an active recent ticket in Django trac, [`#16256` More class based views: formsets derived generic views](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16256). If all goes well, new generic views will be added to Django: `FormSetsView`, `ModelFormSetsView` and `InlineFormSetsView`. Particularly, the last one ‘provides a way to show and handle a model with it's inline formsets’.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. If I understand you correctly, my case is a bit different though as I only have one form, but it represents multiple models. I have edited my question to clarify it.

Comment: Exactly the right example from the docs, I'll give subclassing the base view a try.

Comment: It is worth noting that ModelForm and ModelFormset implements similar interface: `is_valid(), save(), clean(), errors` so basically if Django were consistent there should be SaveableView that used only mentioned interface and could work on both forms and formsets. It could be used to implement even multiple forms and formsets in one generic view.

Comment: Eh, one page can have both a search form and a "normal" form.

Comment: Of course, there might be a need for multiple forms on one page. If that's a requirement, I'd handle it on client side, saving data with AJAX. But as long as we're using Django's generic views, and we aren't ready to implement measures to prevent user from accidentally losing entered data, I'd limit the number of editable forms in primary page section to one.

Answer (score 5):

**Present fields from two models on a single view page**

You have to extend django.views.generic.View class and override get(request) and post(request) methods.

This is how I did that.

I'm using **Django 1.11**.

This is how my form (consisted of two forms) looks like:
[image: User registration form]

My **View** class which renders my two forms:

```
from django.views.generic import View

class UserRegistrationView(View):
    # Here I say which classes i'm gonna use
    # (It's not mandatory, it's just that I find it easier)
    user_form_class = UserForm
    profile_form_class = ProfileForm
    template_name = 'user/register.html'

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return render(request, 'user/already_logged_in.html')
        # Here I make instances of my form classes and pass them None
        # which tells them that there is no additional data to display (errors, for example)
        user_form = self.user_form_class(None)
        profile_form = self.profile_form_class(None)
        # and then just pass them to my template
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form})

    def post(self, request):
        # Here I also make instances of my form classes but this time I fill
        # them up with data from POST request
        user_form = self.user_form_class(request.POST)
        profile_form = self.profile_form_class(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save(commit=False)
            user_profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)

            # form.cleaned_data is a dictionary which contains data validated
            # by fields constraints (Say we have a field which is a number. The cleaning here would 
            # be to just convert a string which came from the browser to an integer.)
            username = user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']

            # This will be clarified later 
            # You can save each object individually if they're not connected, as mines are (see class UserProfile below)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.userprofile = user_profile
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                return redirect('user:private_profile')

        # else: # form not valid - each form will contain errors in form.errors
        return render(request, self.template_name, {
            'user_form': user_form,
            'profile_form': profile_form
        })
```

I have a `User` and `UserProfile` models.
`User` is `django.contrib.auth.models.User` and `UserProfile` is as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField('self', null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Some address 42')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user:public_profile', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return 'username: ' + self.user.username + '; address: ' + self.address

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User) # see Clarification 1 below
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created: # See Clarification 2 below
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance, address=instance.userprofile.address)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.userprofile.save()
```

**Clarification 1:** @receiver(post_save, sender=User)

- when User is saved (I wrote user.save() somewhere (user is an instance of class User) ) UserProfile will also be saved.

**Clarification 2:** if created: (clarification from the View class)

- If User is being CREATED, make a UserProfile 
                      where user = User instance which was just now submitted trough a UserForm
- address is gathered from ProfileForm and added to the user instance before 
                      calling user.save()

I have two forms:

**UserForm:**

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True), required=True)
    password_confirmation = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True), required=True)

    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password', 'password_confirmation')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        password_confirmation = cleaned_data.get("password_confirmation")

        if password != password_confirmation:
            self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()
            self.fields['password_confirmation'].widget = forms.PasswordInput()

            self.add_error('password', "Must match with Password confirmation")
            self.add_error('password_confirmation', "Must match with Password")
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Password and Password confirmation do not match"
            )
```

**ProfileForm:**

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('address',)
```

I hope that I understood your question well and that this will help you (and others to come). :)

Comment: I think this should now be the accepted answer. It's clean, leverages Django's classes & builtin functionalities, and is well commented. Thanks for posting that.

Comment: The only thing that may be worth adding would be the Signal system so that the Userprofile receives the signals from User when that User is saved.

Comment: You are welcome! I totally forgot Django now, since this was more than 3 years ago... :D But, feel free to edit the answer as you please.

Answer (score 2):

One of the principles of django is that you can build up one big form out of several smaller forms, with only one submit-button. That's why the `<form>`-tags aren't generated by django itself.

The problem with generic views, class based or not, and multiple such forms in the background, is of course that the sky's the limit. The forms may be related somehow: a "mother"-form and and optional extra data that depends on the data in the mother (onetoone, say). Then there's the model that is connected to several other models through foreign keys and/or intermediary tables where you'd use form+formsets. Then there's the all-formset kind of page, like in the admin when you make some fields editable directly in the list view. Each of these are different types of multi form views, and I don't think it would be fruitful to make one generic view that would cover all cases.

If you have a "mother" model though, you can use a standard `UpdateView` or `CreateView` and add methods for the extra forms that are called from `get()` and `post()`, after the code that deals with the mother model. In `form_valid()` for instance, if the mother-form is valid you can process the other forms. You'll have the pk of the mother that you then use to connect up the data in the other forms.