# Can't update User and UserProfile in one View?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I use `UpdateView` to update user account. User consists of User and UserProfile like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='userprofile')
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True)
```

Now, I've created a class `UpdateView` to be able to update for example `UserProfile` - telephone which works.

FORM:

```
class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('telephone',)
```

URLS:

```
url(r'^edit-profile$',view=views.UserUpdate.as_view(),name='user_update'),
```

VIEW:

```
# @login_required
class UserUpdate(UpdateView):
    form_class = UserProfileUpdateForm
    context_object_name = 'user_update'
    template_name = 'auth/profiles/edit-profile.html'
    success_url = 'success url'

    def get_object(self,queryset=None):
        return self.request.user.userprofile

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #save cleaned post data
        clean = form.cleaned_data
        self.object = form.save()
        return super(UserUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Now, I want to be able to change some attributes which belongs to User and some attributes which belongs to `UserProfile`.

I've already tried to change `UserProfileUpdateForm` fields variable but It does not work at all...

```
class UserProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('telephone','model.user.first_name',) <- this does not work, I want to add to the form attribute 'first_name' which belongs to User, not UserProfile
```

Do you know what to do to be able to change telephone, first_name, last_name etc. using `UpdateView`?

Answer (score 2):

`UpdateView` is only made to handle one model with no relations. However, the wonderful [`django-extra-views`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views) library provides CBVs for models and inline relations.

```
class UserProfileInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = models.UserProfile
    form = UserProfileUpdateForm
    extra = 0
    def get_factory_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(UserProfileInline,self).get_factory_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({"min_num": 1})
        return kwargs

class UserCreate(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model=User
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = reverse('some-success-url')
    # REQUIRED - fields or exclude fields of User model
    template_name = 'your_app/user_profile_update.html'
```

Be sure to check out the [documentation](https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for information on the variables passed to your template and how to work with [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Answer (score 0):

You have to create second form for `User` as well. Then pass it to the same `UpdateView` as a second `form_class`.

Note*: you may need to override `get` and `post` methods for `UpdateView`. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15499249/5253807) might help.

Render both forms in one template under one `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ first_form }}
    {{ second_form }}
</form>
```