# Django one-to-one relationships in one form

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a registration form for a extension of django's user model. It has a two relationships, one to `User` and `Address`. The form needs to have all the fields from `User`, `UserDetails` and `Address`. But i'm struggling to get the correct view and form. Just having a `ModelForm` for `UserDetails` combined with `FormView` doesn't add the fields for `User` and `Address`.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)


class UserDetails(model.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Address(model.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

The form and view look like this:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orchestra
        fields = '__all__'

class UserRegistrationView(FormView):
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'users/register.html'

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Please post your view and form, and explain exactly what you want to do, "struggling to get the correct view and form" is not enought.

Comment: I've added the view and form. This gives me just a foreign key choice field for user instead of the charfield fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create different forms for each model. Then combine all the instances created from the forms. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24011448/2315022)

Answer (score 0):

You missed the **unicode** or **str** method declaration in model classes. You should always declare it. 
Remember that str is for python 3.x, and unicode for python 2.x.

Here is an example for class Address and python 2:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.field1, self.field2)
```