# Django Form Fields arent displayed

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to display to simple search Forms in a view.

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Vehicle_Search_by_VIN(forms.Form):
    vin = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    first_registration_date = models.DateField()

class Vehicle_Search_by_Plate(forms.Form):
    plate = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    last_four_diggits_of_vin = models.DateField(max_length=4)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from .forms import *


class VehicleSearch(View):
    template = 'vehicle_search_template.html'
    cxt = {
        'Search_by_VIN': Vehicle_Search_by_VIN(),
        'Search_by_Plate': Vehicle_Search_by_Plate()
    }
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template, self.cxt)
```

**my template-file:**

```
<form class="by_vin" method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ Search_by_VIN.as_p }}
    
        <button name='action' value='login' type="submit">Suchen</button>
</form>
    
    <form class="by_plate" method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ Search_by_Plate.as_p }}
    
        <button name='action' value='signup' type="submit">Suchen</button>
    </form>
```

But as a result only the submit buttons are displayed in the view. Does anybody know why my forms aren't being rendered?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: Can class-based views accept two forms at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497693/django-can-class-based-views-accept-two-forms-at-a-time)

Answer (score 0):

in `views.py`, i think, you are missing `*args` and `**kwargs` parameters in `get()` function

```
class VehicleSearch(View):

    template = 'vehicle_search_template.html'

    cxt = {
        'Search_by_VIN': Vehicle_Search_by_VIN(),
        'Search_by_Plate': Vehicle_Search_by_Plate()
    }

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  # HERE
        return render(request, self.template, self.cxt)
```

## Update

By default, **class-based views** does only support a **single** form per view but you can counter this limitation with few options depending on your logic. refer to this thread [Django: Can class-based views accept two forms at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497693/django-can-class-based-views-accept-two-forms-at-a-time)

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

try to give full path in your template variable for e.g. if your app name is my_app then `template = 'my app/vehicle_search_template.html'`